# apache camel data validation issue

Tags: validation, parallel-processing, apache-camel, filereader

I am new to camel, reading a data file (flat text file) using multiple threads.
Able to read data and store into pojo. Getting issue in validation.
Issue is in validation. While reading line by line I am storig records in the context in a map. Now validation has to be across the line. Like some of the record has suppose ids that should be defined in earlier record. Here is my route:-

```java
get("readerService","fileReader")
  .log(...)
  .process(e->readerService.init(...))
  .split(...)
      .streaming()
      .parallelProcessing(...)
      .threads(...)
      .process(e -> readerService.read(e, ctx)
      // tranforms read record to pojo and stores into map in ctx
      .process(e -> recTransformer(e, ctx)
      .process(e -> myValidator(e, ctx)
      .end()
```

problem is read service is reading 10 data randomly and transformer reads, creates pojo and stores into map in context. But validator also getting called each time when the complete record is not read.
In some cases it is trying to validate record when previous record is not stored into map due to parallel processing.

I would like to know how to call   .process(e->myValidator(e, ctx)
after entire file is read and map is complete. That will resolve my issue. Any suggestion will be great.

Comment: Everything between a `.split(...)` and `end()`  will be called for every split exchange. If you want to call `.process(e -> myValidator(e, ctx)` outside of split definition you could try to move it below `.end()`

Comment: Thanks for the info. It worked.